# Tailwind doesn't apply some font size classes

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So I started using Tailwind 2.0 in my React project and most things seem to work fine. Colors, sizing, flexbox, grid, etc. No problem with these utilities so far. But for some reason some font-size classes won't work properly. For instance, if I use `text-lg`, the style is applied
[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb4pe.png).

But if I try anything bigger than that, like `text-2x1` or higher, [the class isn't applied.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eJrn.png)

I searched around a lot but didn't find anything that could help me.

I don't know it this helps, but that's my config file (even though it was already happening even before I made any change to it):

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        normal: "#A8A878",
        poison: "#A040A0",
        psychic: "#F85888",
        grass: "#78C850",
        ground: "#E0C068",
        ice: "#98D8D8",
        fire: "#F08030",
        rock: "#B8A038",
        dragon: "#7038F8",
        water: "#6890F0",
        bug: "#A8B820",
        dark: "#705848",
        fighting: "#C03028",
        ghost: "#705898",
        steel: "#B8B8D0",
        flying: "#A890F0",
        electric: "#F8D030",
        fairy: "#EE99AC",
        noType: "lightgray",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

index.css has nothing but the bare minimum for Tailwind to work:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Here's the repository: https://github.com/TheSirion/pokedex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are using the wrong className, `text-2x1` className is wrong instead you should use `text-2xl`.

For your reference, check the official [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size) to see more classNames for font-size.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I spent so long trying to figure it out just because I confounded a lowercase L for a 1. Wow!

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe this tripped me up too. For what it's worth, I think the docs could really make this detail much clearer ...